# Expand/Collapse vuetify expansion panel with vuex

Tags: html, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

I am having 3 expansion panels. By default, only 1 is enabled and other two's are disabled. What I am trying to achieve is that **when user submit the form then other two expansion panels enabled and open 2nd panel at that time but 3rd panel remains closed. If I click on first panel then other two should disabled and collpased. On expanding any of the 1 panel, another 2 panels remains closed**. To achieve this I am using vuetify expansion panel with vuex. Here is my code:

1-Store.js

```
//store.js
const state = {
   userDetails: null,
   form1: false,
   userFormTwo: null,
   panel: [true, false, false]
}

// getters
const getters = {
   userDetails: state => {
      return state.userDetails;
   },
   form1: state =>{
      return state.form1;
   },
   userFormTwo:state =>{
      return state.userFormTwo;
   },
   panel: state => {
      return state.panel;
   }
}

// actions
const actions = {
   addUserDetails(context, payload) {
      context.commit('onAddedUserDetails', payload);
   },
   userFormTwo(context,payload){
    context.commit('onUserFormtwo',payload);
   },
   togglePanel(context, payload) {
      context.commit('togglePanelHandler', payload);
   }
}

// mutations
const mutations = {

   onAddedUserDetails(state, payload) {
      state.userDetails = payload;
      state.form1 = true;
      state.panel = [false, true, false];
   },
   onUserFormtwo(state,payload){
      state.userFormTwo = payload;
      state.panel = [false,false,true]
   },
   togglePanelHandler(state,payload){
      state.panel = payload;
      if(state.panel[0] == true ){
        state.panel[1] = false;
            state.panel[2] = false;
            state.form1 = false;
      }
   }
}

export default {
   state,
   getters,
   actions,
   mutations,
}
```

2- Expansion.vue- Where I am importing the components

```
//Expansion.vue
<template>
   <div>
        <v-expansion-panel dark expand v-model="expansionPanelToggle">
         <user-form></user-form>
         <reports></reports>
         <table></table>
      </v-expansion-panel>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import userForm from './Component/userForm'
import reports from './Component/reports'
import table from './Component/table'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters("panel"),
        expansionPanelToggle: {
            get() {
                return this.$store.getters.panel;
            },
            set(val) {
                this.$store.dispatch("togglePanel", val);
            }
        }
    },
    components:{
        userForm:userForm,
        reports:Reports,
        table:Table
    }
}
</script>
```

3- UserForm.vue

```
<template>
  <v-expansion-panel-content>
      <v-card>
         <v-card-text>
            <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid">
               <v-flex lg4 xl4 xs12 sm6 md6>
                  <v-text-field v-model="userInfo.firstName" :rules="inputRules.basictextRules" label="First Name*" required></v-text-field>
               </v-flex>
               <v-flex lg4 xl4 xs12 sm6 md6>
                  <v-text-field v-model="userInfo.lastName" :rules="inputRules.basictextRules" label="Last Name*" required></v-text-field>
               </v-flex>
                    <div>
                <v-btn pl-0 ml-0 large @click="addUserDetails">Continue To Payment</v-btn>
                    </div>
                </v-form>
         </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
  </v-expansion-panel-content>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
    data () {
        return {
            valid: false,
            userInfo:{
                firstName : '', 
                lastName :'',
           },
                inputRules: {
                    basictextRules: [v => !!v || 'This field should not be empty.'],
                    emailRules: [
                        v => !!v || "This field should not be empty.",
                        v =>
                        /^\w+([.-]?\w+)*@\w+([.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(v) ||
                        "E-mail must be valid"
                    ]
                },
         }
      },
      methods: {
         addUserDetails(){
                this.$refs.form.validate()
                if(this.valid == true){
                    this.$store.dispatch("addUserDetails", this.userInfo);
                }               
            }
      }
   }
</script>
```

When user is added I enabled the other two panels by changing disabled field to false through vuex.  Here you can see how i am changing "disabed" attribute value:

Reports.vue

```
// reports.vue
<template>
   <v-expansion-panel-content class="primary" :disabled="!form1" :class="{'display-form': !form1}" >
   <h4 >Reports</h4>
   <v-btn icon @click="userFormTwo"><v-icon>send</v-icon></v-btn>
</v-expansion-panel-content>
</template>
<script>
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';      
   export default{
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(["form1"])
        },
        methods: {
           userFormTwo(){
             this.$store.dispatch("userFormTwo",'submit');
           }
        }
   }
</script>
```

After submit userformTwo, 3rd panels open and rest of the panels closed.
 All is working fine through this code. the issue I am facing is between other 2 panels except 1st panel. I am unable to open exactly 1 panel at that time. Values for 2nd and 3rd panel are  clashing with each other due to which expansion panels are not closing if other is open. Hope I have explained my question clearly. If anyone is having any doubt please ask me. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any benefit in your using an expansion panel in parent component **Expansion.vue** and having expansion panel content in the **User.vue** and **Reports.vue**.  I have had success with content in the sub components that does not have expansion panel content tags...just cards or text.  They hold your content and form data.  So **Expansion.vue** would look more like:

```
<v-expansion-panel v-model="panel" expandable>
  <v-expansion-panel-content :key="1">
     <div slot="header">
       <h2>User Form</h2>
     </div>
     <user-form></user-form>
  </v-expansion-panel-content>
   <v-expansion-panel-content :key="2">
     <div slot="header">
       <h2>Reports</h2>
     </div>
     <reports></reports>
   </v-expansion-panel-content>
   ...
</v-expansion-panel>
```

So if you are trying to submit form data using panel 1 and then have panel 1 close and then open panel 2, you just want your action addUserDetails to commit a mutation that changes the state of panel to [false, true, false].  Your code has a getter named panel and a state named panel.  This should not be the case.  Isn't that causing an error? I see no benefit in using the getter.  I would use mapState in Expansion.vue and not mapGetters.  The sub components can dispatch actions that commit mutations that change the state to what you wish.

```
panel: {
   get() {
     return this.$store.state.panel;
   },
   set(val) {
     this.$store.commit("togglePanelHandler", val);
   }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ExcessJudgement thanks for the reply. I tried your answer but it did't helped me so I have explained my problem more in detail now. Please check and let me know if there is any solution for it.